# Trying to recreate a solution given for a question, need a little assistance

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Trying to recreate a solution given for [ASP.NET MVC - Taking search criteria as input, and displaying the results, in the same View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48250715/asp-net-mvc-taking-search-criteria-as-input-and-displaying-the-results-in-th), but not sure where to find the querymanager that derloopkat uses in his example.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Query(FormQueryModel model)
{
    var queryManager = new QueryManager(model);
    model.QueryResults = queryManager.GetResults();
    return View(model);
}
```

My ViewModels

```
   public class PartRequestInfoSearch
        {
            public int? Building { get; set; }
            public int? PartType { get; set; }
            public int? PartStatus { get; set; }

            public Nullable<System.DateTime> tmpStartDate { get; set; }
            public Nullable<System.DateTime> tmpEndDate { get; set; }

            public int PageSize { get; set; }

           public List<RequestedPartInfo> RequestedPartInfos { get; set; }

            public PartRequestInfoSearch()
            {
                this.RequestedPartInfos = new List<RequestedPartInfo>();
            }

        }

    }

 public class RequestedPartInfo
    {
        public int idPartRequest { get; set; }
        public string Building { get; set; }
        public string RequestNumber { get; set; }
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }
        public string VendorPartNumber { get; set; }
        public string PartDescription { get; set; }
        public int StockQTY { get; set; }
        public int RequestQTY { get; set; }
        public int ShippedQTY { get; set; }
        public string PartStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: It is a stub class to demonstrate a query and search results. For that question the details of an actual implementation isn't important.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a search page that takes the multiple search criteria and returns the results on the same page.. much like what he's describing.

Comment: The details for such a class would depend on the data source. It was not specified in the original question. You will need to provide that to find a concrete solution.

Comment: So like Entity Framework and the database?

Comment: That could work, yes. How you choose to implement retrieving your data is up to you. I suggest you pick an approach and try it out. If you get stuck with your implementation, provide a [MCVE].